# how to bind the function and the tag together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an function which I want to bind on some input-tags. You can see two examples in the code-snippet below. the second example works so far but I want to use the function more often so I tried to make it stand alone. You can see the result of my attemp at example one. it doesent work. I did not understand how I have to bind the function and the tag together. Can sombody help?

```js
var tags = [ 'Test', 'noch ein Test', 'Testwort']; 

/* Example one: This doesn't work*/
function narrow() {
  //var $x = e.data.x;
  var isValid = false;
  for (i in x) {
   if (x[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
    isValid = true;
   }
  }
  if (!isValid) {
   this.value = previousValue
  } else {
   previousValue = this.value;
  }
}

$( "#_id" ).autocomplete({
              minLength: 0,
              source: tags
});
$('#_id').bind('keyup', {x: tags}, narrow);

/* Example two: This works*/
$( "#_id_2" ).autocomplete({
              minLength: 0,
              source: tags
}).keyup(function() {
    var isValid = false;
    for (i in tags) {
        if (tags[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isValid) {
        this.value = previousValue
    } else {
        previousValue = this.value;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="_id" name="xxx"> <input id="_id_2" name="xxxy">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your for-loop in narrow to:

```
function narrow() {
    ...
    for (i in tags) {
       if (tags[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
            isValid = true;
        }
...
```

and change the keyup-binding to:

```
$('#_id').bind('keyup', narrow);
```

Comment: but this dont solve the problem. for each input i have differnt tags

Answer (score 0):

you can try with below script:

```
$('#_id').bind('input keydown mousedown', function() {...});
```

Hope it resolves your issue.

Thanks

Comment: the problem was, that I want to have one function, which I can use on input a with tagss_a and input b with tags_b and input c with tags_c etc.

Comment: the function should stand alone as it is shown in the first example. becouse I dont want to have the same code on each input. and every input uses autocomplete with other tags inside...

Comment: do you mean you want to create a common function where you can pass iput tags as parameter and apply those input tags to `input `. Right ?

Comment: Yes. Each input has a autocomplete-feature with own tags and the function you see in my example one and two causes that you can only choose the autocomplete-tags but no other tags. And this feature I want to have for all my autocomplete-input-fields, so that I dont have to write the same code for each of them.